# issue with junit test case! avoid code duplication

Tags: java, junit

I am  writting jnuit test case for testing API.

my class is as follows

```
class MyTest extends TestCase{
    List<String>  argList;
    public MyTest(){
     //read argList from File
    }



     testMyTest(){
       //callmy api
         myApi(arg1);
       }

}
```

Now i want make a seperate testcase for each of the 50 args.Args are read from File. I dont want to write a seperate method  for calling myApi with different args.How can i do it?
I dont want to write sperate methods like

```
testMyTest1(){
   //callmy api
     myApi(arg1);
   }

testMyTest1(){
   //callmy api
     myApi(arg2);
   }
```

Comment: too little info given. whats is argument type, what output is expect from myApi call, how to verify if a test case has passed etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Parameterized tests or Theories (since JUnit 4.4). For more details use

- http://blogs.oracle.com/jacobc/entry/parameterized_unit_tests_with_junit
- http://blogs.oracle.com/jacobc/entry/junit_theories

Comment: These links are no longer available

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [parameterized test](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/) for this.

Comment: Is there a way to run Parameterized test on just a subset of the tests? i.e. One set of tests should be run only once, another set should be run multiple times once for each parameter? Or is this generally done using multiple test classes?

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String[] args = new String[] {.....};

@Test
public void myTest(){
   for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
      myApi(args[i];
   }
}
```

The above answers your question I think, however it is not good JUnit practice. It is best that each test method only invokes the method under test one time with one test condition. That way if multiple things are wrong, you get a separate error for each rather than dealing with one at a time. This would suggest the following:

```
private static final String[] args = new String[] {.....};

private void testMyTest(String arg){
    myApi(arg);
}

@Test
public void myTest0(){
  testMyTest(args[0]);
}
@Test
public void myTest1(){
  testMyTest(args[1]);
}
```

Probably the best mechanism is to do the first option above but using the [ErrorCollector](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) rule to allow for multiple errors to be reported.

**Edit** I stand corrected, jordao's answer regarding parameterized tests is really the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing usually is made with assertions. You don't need to write a method for each argument, but execute different assertions based on your arguments.

One way for doing it would be:

```
class MyApiTest extends TestCase {
    List<String>  argList;

    public MyApiTest() {}

    public testMyApi() {
        assertTrue(testMyApi(arg1));
        assertFalse(testMyApi(arg2));
        assertNull(testMyApi(arg3));
        assertEquals(testMyApi(arg4), testMyApi(arg5));
    }
}
```

I'd even prefer using annotations, like

```
class MyApiTest {
    @Before
    public setUp() {}

    @After
    public tearDOwn() {}

    @Test
    public testMyApi() {
        Assert.assertTrue(testMyApi(arg1));
        Assert.assertFalse(testMyApi(arg2));
        Assert.assertNull(testMyApi(arg3));
        Assert.assertEquals(testMyApi(arg4), testMyApi(arg5));
    }
}
```